# Create a git thin-pack using libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

Is it possible to create a thin pack using libgit2? If so, how would I do this?

I can create a thin-pack using pure git commands, something like this should do it:

```
echo "^827935eb178f4f2e6b0d8bafe31e5d8a998d0a3c" > revs
echo "fce1b85f5b9cf47573c933226223e912a2f1165e" >> revs
(git pack-objects --stdout --thin --revs < revs) > pack-test.pack
```

> `git log --online`

```
fce1b85 small change
827935e BigFile
60d5d58 trivial readme change
```

`827935e` is already uploaded, so I want to create a pack which only contains the delta between `fce1b85` and `827935e` hence a thin-pack is essential here.

git produces a desirable output, libgit2 however (building a packfile with one commit), produces a large packfile.

My code basically does this:

```
git_packbuilder_new(...)
git_packbuilder_insert_commit(commit=fce1b85)
git_packbuilder_write(...)
```

Unfortunately there is no way to specify that you want a thin pack.
Is there any way to get the same behaviour as one would do with git?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that it's not possible in its current state. But since I am currently working on a custom git-repo format, I was able to put something together. What I did is basically:

```
git_packbuilder_new(...)
git_packbuilder_insert_commit(commit=827935e)
git_packbuilder_insert_commit(commit=fce1b85)
git_packbuilder_write(...)
```

This generates a pack which may contain the delta between the desired commit and its parent. Then I have code which **parses the packfile and index to produce a stripped packfile and index file without the parent commit** (`827935e`).

This requires way more memory/space (It's probably okay for small packs) and increases complexity but from my view it's the only way if you don't want to directly modify libgit2.